# How can i crawl search engine result

Tags: asp.net, search, search-engine, web-crawler

Is it feasible to build a page (asp.net) to crawl search engine result and then display in my own page ?

My colleague want to develop a page contain a search box, when user input keyword and click search, it will pass to search engine (such as google) and crawl the result. And then insert the result into database and display the result in my page.

Comment: it's not a easy task men , go for bounty ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use google search API, but its deprecated now.
There are other ways also, but search engines can easily detect non human doing search. So its not advisable.

Comment: hi, if the search engine is not google, just some 3rd party search engine... is there any way to crawl the result ? thanks